# What is "Partial order reduction" as discussed in: Exploiting The Laws of Order in Smart Contracts?

Tags: mining

I am trying to understand the concept of partial-order reduction techniques discussed in the paper:

Exploiting The Laws of Order in Smart Contracts

Partial ordering is a technique to avoid event-ordering bugs, a concept closely reated to transaction ordering bugs.

Available at: [Link of paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11605)

I can’t understand what is meant by partial order reduction. It talks about happens-before relationship, which means that one event is occurring before another, and we have to maintain this order; otherwise, we would get an exception. However, I understand from the term “partial order reduction” that the term reduction in “partial order reduction” means that we are considering only two events and not many events. The term partial is used because we are considering independent functions, i.e., we are not saying that function, f1, occurs before function, f2, and function, f2, occurs before function, f1. The paper says:

> The implementation strategy for extracting weak happensbefore (WHB) is
> straight-forward. We execute the two differing orderings of each pair
> of events in a given trace. If we observe that one order leads to
> exception, and other does not, we inductively learn this relationship.
> We can also identify which functions are independent as per the
> natural extension of the definition from HB to WHB.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.